# Build error from heroku CLI or github. Can't deploy new content

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku

I have been using heroku to deploy a website. So far everything was going great. After a few months without using it, I decided to update it to which I found myself facing an error I can't comprehend.

I have tried to update all my dependencies to either the last recommended and the last released. I have updated nodejs, npm and updated the package file. All with no success.
All I want is to be able to update the content I have in my current app.

Below you can see my build log.

```
   -----> Node.js app detected

   -----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false

   -----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 10.x...
   Downloading and installing node 10.15.1...
   Using default npm version: 6.4.1

   -----> Restoring cache
   Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
   Module installation may take longer for this build

   -----> Building dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

   > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt
   > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@10.15.1 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@10.15.1 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
   make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
   make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
   sed: can't read ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
   rm: cannot remove './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o.d.raw': No such file or directory
   bcrypt_lib.target.mk:103: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o' failed
   make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
   make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
   gyp ERR! build error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
   gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
   gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt
   gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
   Failed to execute '/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
   ../src/bcrypt.cc: In function ‘void encode_salt(char*, u_int8_t*, u_int16_t, u_int8_t)’:
   ../src/bcrypt.cc:132:1: warning: ‘__builtin___snprintf_chk’ output may be truncated before the last format character [-Wformat-truncation=]
    encode_salt(char *salt, u_int8_t *csalt, u_int16_t clen, u_int8_t logr)
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
   In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:862:0,
                    from ../src/bcrypt.cc:48:
   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:65:44: note: ‘__builtin___snprintf_chk’ output between 4 and 5 bytes into a destination of size 4
           __bos (__s), __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
                                               ^
   ../src/bcrypt.cc: In function ‘void bcrypt(const char*, const char*, char*)’:
   ../src/bcrypt.cc:165:1: warning: ‘__builtin___snprintf_chk’ output may be truncated before the last format character [-Wformat-truncation=]
    bcrypt(const char *key, const char *salt, char *encrypted)
    ^~~~~~
   In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:862:0,
                    from ../src/bcrypt.cc:48:
   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:65:44: note: ‘__builtin___snprintf_chk’ output between 4 and 5 bytes into a destination of size 4
           __bos (__s), __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
                                               ^
     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
   ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:10: fatal error: nan.h: No such file or directory
    #include <nan.h>
             ^~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   bcrypt_lib.target.mk:103: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o' failed
   make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
   make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
   gyp ERR! build error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
   gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
   gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_7a23228fc603a8f673be221b4d53bbc2/node_modules/bcrypt
   gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.X8NUf/_logs/2019-02-08T12_13_11_380Z-debug.log
   -----> Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   Some possible problems:

   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

   Love,
   Heroku

   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
   !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Node.js 10.15.1, you should take a look at this [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#version-compatibility) for version compatibility.

As stated in the repo...

> node-gyp only works with stable/released versions of node. Since the bcrypt module uses node-gyp to build and install you'll need a stable version of node to use bcrypt.

So you will either need to switch to node.js 8.* to use bcrypt 1.0.3 or update your bcrypt to >=3.

Comment: I updated bcrypt to >3 version and it worked.
The first time I tried to update bcrypt I didn't noticed that my npm wasn't working properly and therefore "npmm bcrypt update" didn't go through. I had to completely uninstall bcrypt and later install it again.

Comment: Any Reason why this is happening?

Comment: Reverting back to node.js 8.* was never an option as Heroku only supports the current node.js supported runtimes.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#supported-runtimes

Comment: I think the syntax is `npm update bcrypt`, and you can move down to version 8.x of the node.js runtime since it is supported by heroku. In your package.json you can set `engine` and then `node` to 8.11 or any 8.x version you would like.